# Using defined classes as edge weight for an undirected graph in graph boost library

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

I am new to *Boost Graph Library* and have questions concerning undirected graphs.

My problem is, a 2D space, in which several landmarks are positioned. At the beginning one `Master-landmark` is defined and the goal is to compute the relative poses from the `Master-landmark` to all other landmarks. Since the grid is to big to see it all at once, I get only local information meaning the relative connection/pose between two or more landmarks (the `Master-landmark` does not have to be in every image). Given these local information I need to build a tree in order to get the paths from the `Master-landmark` to the other landmarks. So far so good.
Since the landmark observation is done by another program, I build a matrix, where the information about the landmark relations are encoded (were two landmarks seen together? if yes, relative pose if not 0). This matrix is the so-called `tag_relation_mat` matrix of size `N×N`. `N` defines the number of landmarks and both rows and columns of the matrix represent all `N` landmarks to encode their relation. Each element (if there is a connection between two landmarks otherwise it is `0`) is a `rel_marker_pose` consisting of: 2D pose (x- and y-values) and an error value (high value is bad). In other words, the `tag_relation_mat` is a matrix which encodes all valid connections between the landmarks.
Based on this matrix I'd like to generate an undirected graph and compute relative poses from the `Master-landmark` to all others given the best error value.

So what I am basically doing (with the help of [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp)) right now is

- to build up a undirected graph and
- solve it with the `dijkstra_shortest_paths` algorithm

The outcome is the combined weight (from master-landmark to landmark) and the parent of the landmark.

Given this information, I am recursively generating the paths from each landmark to the master-landmark by combining the transformations given by the `N×N` matrix:

.h file:

```
// Edge weight.
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> EdgeWeightProperty;

typedef adjacency_list < boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
    boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty > Graph; //graph type

typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex; //vertex descriptor
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge; //edge descriptor
typedef std::pair<int, int> _edge;

class GraphTree {

public:
    GraphTree(int no_of_tags) {
        this->num_vertices = no_of_tags;

        //generate vertices
        for(int i = 0; i < no_of_tags; i++) {
            Vertex v  = boost::add_vertex(this->undirected_graph);
            idx_to_vertex.insert({i, v});
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief generateTree generates tree graph with tags as edges and 
     */
    void generateTree();

    /**
     * @brief solveTree thin tree based on chosen solver
     */
    std::vector<rel_marker_pose> solveTree(tree_solver solver, int master_vertex_idx);

    /**
     * @brief getRelPosesToMaster given a master tag (either defined or automatically chosen) rel. poses to the other existing tags are computed
     */
    void getRelPosesToMaster(int master_node, std::vector<Vertex> parent_vec, int start_node, rel_marker_pose* rel_m_pose);

private:
    // declare a graph object
    Graph undirected_graph;

    std::map<int, Vertex> idx_to_vertex;

    int num_vertices;//    const int num_vertices = N;
    int num_edges;//int num_edges = sizeof(edge_array)/sizeof(edge_array[0]);

    std::vector<Edge> edge_vec;

};
```

.cpp file:

```
void GraphTree::generateTree() {

for(int i = 0; i < this->num_vertices; ++i) { //iterate over rows (landmark_from)
    for(int j = 0; j < this->num_vertices; ++j) { //iterate over columns (landmark_to)
        double weight = this->tag_relation_mat.at(i).at(j).rel_pose.quality;

        //check if tags have been seen together -> add only relevant edges
        if(this->tag_relation_mat.at(i).at(j).landmark_from != 0 && this->tag_relation_mat.at(i).at(j).landmark_to != 0) {

            boost::add_edge(this->idx_to_vertex[i], this->idx_to_vertex[j], EdgeWeightProperty(weight), this->undirected_graph);

            }
        }
    }
}

std::vector<rel_marker_pose> GraphTree::solveTree(tree_solver solver, int master_vertex_idx) {

    std::vector<rel_marker_pose> master_to_vertex_vec;

    if(solver == tree_solver::Dijkstra) { //http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp

        //create vectors to store the predecessors (p) and the distances from the root (d)
        std::vector<Vertex> p(boost::num_vertices(this->undirected_graph));
        std::vector<double> d(boost::num_vertices(this->undirected_graph));
        //create a descriptor for the source node
        Vertex master_vertex = vertex(master_vertex_idx, this->undirected_graph);

        //evaluate dijkstra on graph g with source s, predecessor_map p and distance_map d
        boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(this->undirected_graph, master_vertex, boost::predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));

        boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_iterator vi, vend;
        for (boost::tie(vi, vend) = boost::vertices(this->undirected_graph); vi != vend; ++vi) {

            rel_marker_pose r_m_p;

            this->getRelPosesToMaster(master_vertex_idx, p, *vi, &r_m_p);

            master_to_vertex_vec.push_back(r_m_p);
        }
    }
    return master_to_vertex_vec;
}

void GraphTree::getRelPosesToMaster(int master_node, std::vector<Vertex> parent_vec, int start_node, rel_marker_pose* rel_m_pose ) {
    rel_m_pose->rel_pose.quality += this->tag_relation_mat.at(start_node).at(parent_vec[start_node]).rel_pose.quality;

    // ...
    // combine the transformations
    // ...

    rel_m_pose->landmark_from = parent_vec[start_node];

    if(parent_vec[start_node] == master_node) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        this->getRelPosesToMaster(master_node, parent_vec, parent_vec[start_node], rel_m_pose);
    }
}
```

Well, it works, but is definitely not the most elegant way! I was wondering:

1. If there is any possibility to add all relevant information directly into the undirected graph (landmark name to the vertices; pose and quality to the edges). So far, it is just the quality, which is then used to solve the graph. So that after generating the graph, I would only need the graph and not merge informations between graph and matrix after solving the graph?
2. Is there an implemented way (in the boost lib) to obtain all visited edges from master-landmark to landmark?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You merely show the approach you _don't want to have_ and don't provide enough code (`tag_relation_mat`?, `rel_marker_pose`?) that would enable us to understand how your existing data structures work.

Comment: @sehe sorry for the delay! I was currently working on another project and did not have the time for this one.... So I tried to edit my post, I hope it is clearer now?Yes I show the approach I don't want to have, so you first see that I already tried some stuff and second since the code works to get an idea what I am doing. What I wand is to make the code more elegant by including all information into the graph so I do not need to look up the info from the martix.